# Trying to check if username and password is correct with each login but code only iterates over last dictionary item

Tags: python, for-loop, oop

```
bank_data = [
    {
        "username": "jordyn123",
        "password": '1234',
        "balance": 100_000

    },
    {
        "username": "ron456",
        "password": '6789',
        "balance": 500
    }
]

class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    # validate username and password
    def cred_valid(self):
        data = []
        for dict in bank_data:
            a = dict['username']
            p = dict['password']
            data.append(BankAccount(a, p))

        if self.username == a and self.password == p:
            print("Youre in")
        elif self.username != a or self.password != p:
            print("Your username and/or password is incorrect. Please try again")
```

i want this to check if the username and password is correct with each login, but it only iterates and recognizes the last thing in the dictionary.

Comment: Your `if` is outside the loop. Think about what the values of `a` and `p` would be _after_ the loop.

Comment: @Selcuk i've also placed it inside the loop, and it checks for both of them instead of what is given in the input

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to check if the user's account already exists, thus you need to compare with all existing accounts.

```
bank_data = [
    {
        "username": "jordyn123",
        "password": '1234',
        "balance": 100_000

    },
    {
        "username": "ron456",
        "password": '6789',
        "balance": 500
    }
]

class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    # validate username and password
    def cred_valid(self):

        check = any([self.username == d['username']
                    and self.password == d['password'] for d in bank_data])
        if check:
            print("Youre in")
        else:
            print("Your username and/or password is incorrect")
        return check


a = BankAccount("ron456", '6789')
print(a.cred_valid())
b = BankAccount("ron456", '679')
print(b.cred_valid())
```

**Note**,this code doesn't check if the balance, it only looks if the user exists in bank_data.